# Convert list of tuples to list of lists while appending from dictionary

Tags: python

Trying to merge data from a mess of structures in python.

First, I am given a list of tuples in the form

```
f = [('str1',7.0), ('str2',2.8), ('str3',11.2)]
```

And a dictionary of the form

```
d = {'aa':'str2', 'bb':'str3', 'cc':'str1'}
```

where every value is unique (no need to check), and every value in d maps one-to-one with a first element in each tuple of f. I need to change f to a list of lists, and append the matching key from d to the appropriate element of the lists within f. In the above example the desired output is

```
output = [['str1',7.0,'cc'], ['str2',2.8,'aa'], ['str3',11.2,'bb']]
```

Right now I'm doing this with nested for loops. What would be the better/"python-y" way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You can swap the key-value pairs in `d` for more efficient solution:

```
f = [('str1',7.0), ('str2',2.8), ('str3',11.2)]
d = {'aa':'str2', 'bb':'str3', 'cc':'str1'}
new_d = {b:a for a, b in d.items()}
new_f = [[a, b, new_d[a]] for a, b in f]
```

Output:

```
[['str1', 7.0, 'cc'], ['str2', 2.8, 'aa'], ['str3', 11.2, 'bb']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Without swapping, it can be written out directly in a more Pythonic comprehension:

```
output = [[dv, f2, dk] for f1, f2 in f for dk, dv in d.items() if dv == f1]
```

In plain English: create a list consisting of lists of `dv, f2, dk` where `f2` is the second value of tuples `(f1, f2)` in `f` and where `dk` and `dv` are the key and value of the items `dk: dv` from `d`, whenever the value of `dv` matches that of `f1`.

Or as a fully functional script:

```
f = [('str1', 7.0), ('str2', 2.8), ('str3', 11.2)]

d = {'aa': 'str2', 'bb': 'str3', 'cc': 'str1'}

desired_output = [['str1', 7.0, 'cc'], ['str2', 2.8, 'aa'], ['str3', 11.2, 'bb']]

output = [[dv, f2, dk] for f1, f2 in f for dk, dv in d.items() if dv == f1]

print(output == desired_output)
```